# Find Vertical spacing of text lines?

Tags: parsing, pdf, itext

In iText we know that certain attributes of text can be extracted:

- `Gs` → graphics state
- Word spacing
- Character spacing
- Font size

But what about **vertical spacing**? For example, in MS Word one sets paragraph spacing {before/after paragraph, line spacing} and these would all be generated to the resultant PDF. If these vertical spacing information needs to be recovered by analyzing the PDF file, is there any operator one should pay attention to?

In [Adobe Portable Document Format Reference 1.3](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/PDF_1.3/PDF%20Reference%201.3.pdf) one might see

- `Th` → horizontal spacing
- `txty` → move text rendering location with respect to the start of the line segment
- `TLM` → **line matrix**
- `TM` → text matrix
- `Tf` → font
- `TS` → text rise

but I haven't found any operator/meta data which directly specifies vertical spacing of the text.
Perhaps this is related to how the current text line `TLM` is positioned? But how is the location of `TLM` determined?

Comment: `TL` explicitly sets the leading (**9.3.1**: Table 105, and **9.3.5**) which is used in `T*`, `'`, and `"`. There is no command for spacing between paragraphs.